# Could not load file or assembly (DarkRift)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've been struggling with a problem in Unity and I would appreciate it if anyone can help me.

I'm using a package called DarkRift, which is used for networking and connecting clients with a server (provided by DarkRift). In order to work with the DarkRift server, I need to write plugins. A plugin is basically a visual studio project, compiled to .dll file, then that file is copied to a certain directory on the server-side.
I've been working with DarkRift for some time now and have done so much with it. It was working perfectly! However, I needed to work with Firestore package from Google.

Hence, I created another plugin, installed Firestore (and every package needed), wrote some simple code using one of Firestore's functions, compiled the project, copied .dll to the server, then ran the server. The problem is whenever I run the server (.exe file), I get an error that says: **"Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Cloud.Firestore, Version=1.0.0.0, ...' or one of its dependencies."**

I get this error when I use any of Firestore's functions. However, if I just include the package (using Google.Cloud.Firestore;) without using any of its functions, I don't get any error. I googled this problem and looked everywhere and could not solve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firestore is distributed as a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Firestore.v1), which indeed has dependencies.
Have you also copied all those dependencies to the server?
It might also be a framework incompatibility.

To get more details about this kind of problem, you can register a logging event handler on [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.8), which fires when assembly resolution fails.

You can also use tools like [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy) to dig into the problematic assembly - it shows you all sorts of metadata and it can decompile the CIL, which is invaluable for debugging strange behavior in third party code.

Assembly loading is kind of slow in .Net, so it only loads them when needed.
Hence the resolution does not fail when no code references the assembly.

Comment: According to this page: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Firestore.v1
Firestore has two dependencies (Google.Apis and Google.Apis.Auth). I installed both of them via NuGet, compiled the whole thing, then ran the Darkrift server. I still get the same problem!

Comment: Well, then in your plugin, hook into the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event and trigger loading the Firestore assembly via reflection (to prevent the loading of your plugin assembly to fail). You could for example use Assembly.Load